# How to add HTML-Payload for all redirections via Location-Header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to intercept all responses with redirection via location header to enrich the payload with HTML meta refresh or redirection via JS?

Comment: Did you look at using HandleInterceptor ? That should help you, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: @SMA that works for redirects in my `@Controller` classes with #afterCompletion(...) method. However there are still redirects not catched by HandleIntercepter (in my case keycloak-client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Solution that works for me and is used during authentication redirection:

Configure a Filter after `LogoutFilter.class`. This Filter wraps `HttpServletResponse`. This wrapper of `HttpServletResponse` overrides `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String)` to print to response writer and `HttpServletResponse#setHeader(String)` to also print to response writer -- in case someone didn't use `#sendRedirect(String)` but set Location header.

The Reason to override `#sendRedirect(String)` ist that the response stream is reset before at the beginn and closes the stream at the end.

No embedded implementation provides by default a payload for redirection.
Tomcat can use 'coyoteResponse.sendRedirect.note' property and print it in redirect. Jetty and Undertow do not print to response writer any payload.

*Note: Not using Location header to redirect slows website response and IMHO makes a horrible user experience.*